# CSS placing 3 pics stacked as header

Tags: css

Hello

I have been reading the doc about CSS and yes, it says how to use an image for background, all the repeat and no repeat stuff etc.

However, it is not actually one pic that makes the header, it is 3 stacked so I cannot write background-image because the last picture replaces its predecessor.

How do you just tell them to stay there ? I am not finding anything in the w3 site

thank you

Comment: Uhh, what? What have you tried? Do you have any code you can paste? You _can_ use more than one background, but it's not very well supported. You'll most likely have to use `<img>` tags within the header itself :)

Comment: please your complete code.........

Comment: do you want to use multiple backgrounds images in single div ?

Comment: I do not recommend multiple backgrounds !! They are not well supported in IE, What i recommend is have 3 DIV stack on top of each other, and use a background image on each. Of course use a png image, with transparency to get the result you need.

Answer (score -1):

Cut the 1px  Image with all three stack and apply it to background. For more details CSS of http://imagewisely.org/ site. It will helps you.